# overflow of the integer type in C#

Tags: c#, integer, max, overflow, min

In the C# language, the maximum and the minimum value that the int type could maintain in itself are -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Why if we add 2 units to the maximum value, the compiler does not show any errors?

It just shows the -2,147,483,646, which is negative and two units larger than the minimum value the int type can save.

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) explains the behavior and how to change it. (as for my previous comment: i genuinely thought that c# works in a checked mode by default. i certainly think it _should_)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It behaves as towards the circle.

You choose one place to start (it is black line here). Then you are going to make a full circle and then you will reach maximum of its size.

Now, instead of having a problem you will start the same circle again(blue line are those 2 numbers) and that is the reason why you move to negative numbers after reaching a maximum of positive.

[image: 1]

This can cause many problems, so it is the best to make some if-else(or something else) to secure your program.

Here is your example. 
When we add something this happens: 2,147,483,647 -> -2,147,483,648 -> -2,147,483,647 ...

If you have used `unsigned int` and tried to decrease them(4,3,2,1,0 ..) then instead of moving to negative numbers you would move to a maximum value which is 4,294,967,295

**Edit:**

> It is runtime behaviour

Credits to Klaus (look comments).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compiler, it is runtime behaviour. Also, you can adjust the behaviour with the `checked(...)` and `unchecked(...)` statements.